# SOQL Query API responds 503

Tags: javascript, rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

Salesforce Mobile SDK: **10.2.0**

Recently we are getting status code 503 errors on the iOS version of app in China region. The error shows up intermittently and not sure what could be the reasons for this.
We are using `force.js` to query and get the data from SF.

```
String queryStr = "SELECT Id,Username,LastName,FirstName,Name, ... FROM User WHERE SystemModstamp> 2023-07-14T13:28:29.139Z AND Id = '" + userId + "'";
force.queryAll(queryStr, function (data) {
//store data in SmartStore soup
}, function (error) {
//status code 503 - below error response
});
```

Anyone know any scenarios where a queryAll API could respond like below error response -

```
error: Failed to complete operation. (com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain 503)
"response":{"statusCode":503,"MIMEType":"text/html","headers":{"Content-Type":"text/html","Pragma":"no-cache","Content-Encoding":"gzip","Server":"AkamaiNetStorage","Content-Length":"123926"},
"suggestedFilename":"queryAll.html",
"body": [ HTML content with message - Service Not Available. This error originated from Salesforce CDN partner ]
"URL":"<domain>/services/data/v55.0/queryAll?q=SELECT Id,Username,LastName,FirstName,Name, ... FROM User WHERE ..."
"expectedContentLength":891240
```